# Define Padding and IV in PKCS7 encryption with BouncyCastle

Tags: encryption, padding, bouncycastle

I'd like to make an encryption in PKCS#7 format using BouncyCastle, by using the org.bouncycastle.cms package.
I need to define the padding and the initial value for encryption, but the classes of cms package don't allow to define this informations,how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 5652 Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS), Section 14, page 54 [states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#page-55):

> Implementations must randomly generate content-encryption keys,
> message-authentication keys, initialization vectors (IVs), and
> padding.

Thus, BouncyCastle implementation follows CMS standard.

Comment: It's ok for the IV, but is it defined which padding is applied? or which algorithm is used to encrypt the session key?

Comment: Padding process is described in section 6.3 of the same RFC. There is no really a session and, thus, no session key for CMS.